# "1 is not a supported code page" JetBrains Rider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, jetbrains-ide, rider

I recently reset my Window 10 and installed Rider for Unity. It showed me error:

```
Project 'Assembly-CSharp' load failed
1 is not a supported code page.
Parameter name: codepage
```

[image]

I searched for this error tried to change Windows 10 language and Speech to English(US). Reinstalled Rider 8 times and Reset 3 times but nothing is changing.

Any help will be appreciated. pls help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to settings > time and languages > window display language > English (United States)

This is all you have to do. Currently, you have an issue with character encoding, selecting US English as a language should fix this.

Answer (score 0):

1 is for us based code page, change your window display language to ENGLISH (United States)

Answer (score 0):

gGo to settings > time and languages > window display language > English (United States)

This is all you have to do. Currently, you have an issue with character encoding, selecting US English as a language should fix this..

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > time and languages > window display language > English (United States)

This is all you have to do. Currently, you have an issue with character encoding, selecting US English as a language should fix this.

rom rom

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I had the same error on Win11 in a different scenario. The answers here will fix the error, but for those who don't want to change the Windows display language, changing the **regional format** to **English (United States)** is enough to solve the problem.

TL;DR:

- Settings > Time & Languages > Regional format > English (United States)